# What happens to the $L^2$ norm of the, magnitude of gradient of a bump function in $\mathbb{R^2}$, if we keep shrinking the bump?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\psi$ be a two dimensional bump function. What happens to the $$\| |\nabla \psi| \|_{L^2}$$ if we keep shrinking the bump, while the amplitude remains same. Does it go to zero or a finite positive value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'shrinking the bump' and keeping its 'amplitude'?

Comment: Do you mean $\psi(x) \to \psi(ax)$, $a$ larger than $1$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri : In bump function formula, there is a $\epsilon$ parameter, and if we decrease it, the support of bump decreases, but the bump amplitude remains same. Its like $g_{\epsilon}(x) = f(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$

Comment: @Chappers yes by changing $a$ we can shrink/expand the function and its support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for simplicity, let's suppose that you shrink it radially equally, that is $f(\alpha x)$ for $\alpha > 1$.

If we make the change from $f(x)$ to $f(\alpha x)$ for some $\alpha >1$, then the change of variable $u=\alpha x$ gives

$$\int_{\Bbb R^2}|x|^2|f(\alpha x)|^2\,dx = \int_{\Bbb R^2} \left|\frac{u}{\alpha}\right|^2 |f(u)|^2 \frac{du}{\alpha^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha^4} \int_{\Bbb R^2} |u|^2 |f(u)|^2\,du. $$

(Here $x$ is a vector and $dx$ represents the area element. I'm too lazy for vector symbols.) You can see that the norm shrinks for the function if $\alpha > 1$. On the other hand, $\nabla(f(\alpha x)) = \alpha( \nabla f) (\alpha x)$, so if you do a change of variable,

$$\int_{\Bbb R^2} |\nabla (f(\alpha x))|^2\,dx = \alpha^2 \int_{\Bbb R^2} |(\nabla f)(\alpha x)|^2\,dx = \int_{\Bbb R^2} |(\nabla f)(u)|^2\,du$$

so the norm is constant for the gradient. This makes a lot of sense if you are cognizant of the uncertainty principle. The inner product of $f$ with itself picks up a factor of $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$. Squaring this (in accordance with the uncertainty principle) cancels the factor from the first integral above and so it all works out the right way.

This is unique to $\Bbb R^2$ and comes from the fact that the radial measure cancels things out just right. In higher dimensions, the norm of the gradient goes to zero because the radial measure power increases.

This can cause some confusion since it seemingly disobeys the uncertainty principle, but most often one considers *normalized* functions when discussing the uncertainty principle. If the dilated function is normalized appropriately, the norm of the gradient will indeed grow as expected.

Comment: I have not digested the details, but looks great. Thank you.

Comment: may be for $\mathbb{R}^N$ we need to take $L^N$ norm, to maintain the similar relation of the multiplying factor, $\alpha^N$

Comment: You have not taken square root for the integral for norm formula, so L^2 norm grows as $\alpha$, similarily I guess for $\mathbb{R}^N$ $L^N$ norm grows as $\alpha$

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right to me! I don't like putting the square roots in. They're a bit ugly :P

Comment: Your answer might be wrong as $\nabla(f(\alpha x)) \ne \alpha \nabla f(x)$ but $\nabla(f(\alpha x)) = \alpha g(\alpha x)$ where $g = \nabla f$

Comment: You're correct. That was a silly typo. I have fixed it and elaborated.

Comment: Great. Now in n dimensions i take L^n norm and that be constant right?

Comment: I am pretty much sure now that the lp norm of gradient of p dimensional bump is invariant to shrinking.